# Box plot with labels and axes, fitted to a div with fixed dimensions

Tags: svg, d3.js, boxplot

Following the [provided example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/box.html) I built a function that draws a box plot to a jQuery accordion tab, which has a certain fixed height & width. The amount of distinct categories varies greatly depending on the incoming data. Currently I'd like to achieve the following in the plotting:

1) Add axes and display labels, [like in this picture](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/images/det1out.png)

2) Always fit the boxes to container width and height. Currently I see that if there are too many categories, some of them end on the second row, ensuring they're not fully seen. In the picture, the div contains 7 boxes but only 4 fit on one row:
[image]

The question is how can these two be implemented? I couldn't even figure out a way to reliably reduce the padding between the boxes without eating into the side numbers on the boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I adopted the original d3.js example to include axes:

http://bl.ocks.org/jensgrubert/7789216

Instead of using individual svg elements as in Mike's implementation, here all boxplots are rendered with in one root element. This makes it easy to add axes.

Best,
Jens

Comment: Looks good. Dc.js has also recently added support fox box plots, which is also worth of taking a look. [Demo here](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/box-plot.html) (link updated).

Answer (score 1):

For the time being I'm using a hack found at Highcharts forum (jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amergin/ZVydP/)). There's also a box plot implementation made with Raphael.js that looks cool ([github](https://github.com/sioked/Raphael-Box-Plot-Library), [example](http://hustle.slalomchi.com/#/results/2))